# My entire Vue app is created twice on page reload, why is this happening?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Putting a console.log() into the created() & mounted() methods of my App.vue component, the App is created & mounted twice on every page refresh.
I've been driving myself crazy trying to find the reason for this, I've stripped my App right to the bones and it's still happening

This is my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'app',
      mounted() {
        console.log('mounted');
      },
      created() {
        console.log('created');
      }
    }
</script>
```

And this is my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import { store } from './store'
import router from './router'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.API_URL;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Found the issue: My webpack config was pointing to same file twice

Comment: can you share your `index.html` file? do you have `<div id="app">` in that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My webpack config was pointing to same file twice